# Counting bytes on all connections traversing a Linux router

Tags: networking, tcp, router, udp, packet

I have a Linux box which works as a router.

How can I measure which connections send and receive how much data?

For each hour, I would like something like:

```
src_addr   src_port  dst_addr         dst_port  proto  packets  bytes
10.1.2.3   34567     100.101.102.103  443       tcp    101      150 KiB
10.1.2.3   53        1.1.1.1          53        udp    21       11 KiB
10.1.2.4   45678     100.101.102.103  443       tcp    452      220 KiB
10.1.2.4   56789     200.201.202.203  25        tcp    105      50 KiB
10.1.2.4   53        1.1.1.1          53        udp    20       10 KiB
```

but with thousands of rows.

Ideally this would be written straight into a database, but an hourly import from a .csv would be fine.

Are there any existing efficient Linux tools which will give me this data, aggregated by the hour?

Or do I need to build my own with C and libpcap?

Answer (score 0):

iftop is a good solution to report connections. [Many other exist as well](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/) : iptraf-ng, nethog, bmon...

According to Alexandre that [explained how to use iftop and output text](https://serverfault.com/questions/379469/iftop-how-to-generate-text-file-with-its-output), your solution is to put

```
iftop -t -s 3600 > log-(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).txt
```

in your crontab every hour.

Comment: This only lists the connections which were most active in the last 40 seconds of the hour, which is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I like [`vnstat`](https://humdi.net/vnstat/) (also [on GitHub](https://github.com/vergoh/vnstat)). I think it does all the things you've asked about - at least it's *configurable*, and actively maintained.

I use it because it doesn't consume many resources, and I've better things to do with compute cycles on my small systems.